# Most efficient way of performing creation of new rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance

I'm implementing a data augmentation script that takes as input a pandas DataFrame and a list of strings (e.g. `variations`). The script should generate new rows for the DataFrame, where each row concatenates an element of `variations`.

For instance, having a DataFrame:

```
Compliment | Sentence_ID
Hi         | 1
Hello      | 2
Hola       | 3
```

And variations `["Elvis", "Monica"]`

The resulting dataframe should be like this:

```
Compliment   | Sentence_ID
Hi           | 1
Hi Elvis     | 1
Hi Monica    | 1
Hello        | 2
Hello Elvis  | 2
Hello Monica | 2
Hola         | 3
Hola Elvis   | 3
Hola Monica  | 3
```

I made some tests with `pd.iterrows()` but it seems to be very slow (~5 minutes) when the dataframe is large. I'd like to know if there is such a more feasible option.

Comment: Is `variations` of big size in your real case?

Comment: Yes, you can consider they'll be large.

Comment: can you give the size of your real dataset? and of the variations list?

Comment: This will be applied in some different datasets, but you can consider that datasets may have between 10-30k rows and variations could have 100-300 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['Compliment'] = df['Compliment'].apply(lambda x: [x] + [f"{x} {v}" for v in variations])
df = df.explode('Compliment')
```

---

```
     Compliment  Sentence_ID
0            Hi            1
0      Hi Elvis            1
0     Hi Monica            1
1         Hello            2
1   Hello Elvis            2
1  Hello Monica            2
2          Hola            3
2    Hola Elvis            3
2   Hola Monica            3
```

Comment: I have to say that `explode` is faster than I expected (although not as much as a cross-merge without post-processing). I added some timings :)

Comment: @mozway, ok, by the way as for "numpy approach": I recently have answered some question and noted that `np.tile` is slower than `np.repeat` : like `%timeit np.tile([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 300)` vs `%timeit np.repeat([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], 300, axis=0).ravel()`

Comment: feedback on your suggestion, it's indeed faster on small lists but the same timing on large inputs. For the current case there is no difference. I guess `tile` as a greater overhead since it has a bit more capabilities than `repeat` ;)

Comment: Great analysis. Thanks for the hard work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `merge`

```
out = df.merge(pd.Series(["","Elvis", "Monica"],name='Compliment'),how='cross')
out['Compliment'] = out[['Compliment_x','Compliment_y']].agg(' '.join, axis=1).str.strip()
out = out.drop(['Compliment_x','Compliment_y'],axis=1)
out
Out[96]: 
   Sentence_ID    Compliment
0            1            Hi
1            1      Hi Elvis
2            1     Hi Monica
3            2         Hello
4            2   Hello Elvis
5            2  Hello Monica
6            3          Hola
7            3    Hola Elvis
8            3   Hola Monica
```

Comment: Oops I hadn't seen your answer, have a quick look on my merge method (might be more efficient) and then I can delete if you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `repeat` and [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
variations =  ["Elvis", "Monica"]

pd.concat([df,
           df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(variations))]
             .assign(Compliment=lambda d: d['Compliment'].add(' ').add(np.tile(variations, len(df))))
          ]).sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
```

Or with a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
l = ['']+[f' {s}' for s in variations]

(df.merge(pd.Series(l, name='suffix'), how='cross')
   .assign(Compliment=lambda d: d['Compliment'].add(d.pop('suffix')))
)
```

Output:

```
     Compliment  Sentence_ID
0            Hi            1
1      Hi Elvis            1
2     Hi Monica            1
3         Hello            2
4   Hello Elvis            2
5  Hello Monica            2
6          Hola            3
7    Hola Elvis            3
8   Hola Monica            3
```

##### timings

N is the number of rows, and there is a fixed length of 200 items in `variation`

[image: df length variation]

Now, N is the number of items in `variation` and `df` has 30K rows:

[image: list length variation]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `pd.concat()`

```
l = ['','Elvis','Monica']
(pd.concat([df]*len(l),keys = l,names = ['name'])
.reset_index(level=0)
.assign(Compliment = lambda x: x['Compliment'] + ' ' + x.pop('name'))
.sort_index(level=0))
```

or

```
(df.assign(t = [l]*len(df)).explode('t')
.assign(Compliment = lambda x: x['Compliment'] + x.pop('t')))
```

Output:

```
     Compliment  Sentence_ID
0           Hi             1
0      Hi Elvis            1
0     Hi Monica            1
1        Hello             2
1   Hello Elvis            2
1  Hello Monica            2
2         Hola             3
2    Hola Elvis            3
2   Hola Monica            3
```